# Hosting a UDP Server

Tags: hosting, udp, gameserver

How do I host a UDP server for free or cheap?
I can't afford to actually buy or rent a physical server.
I have a prototype server application written in C#, and I can probably rewrite it in any platform or language.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Why the thumb down? Is this a bad question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rent time on a virtual server, such as on amazon EC2 or Rackspace cloud or the like. You can get cheaper servers running Linux than windows, so a rewrite might be helpful. But without a machine to run your software on, it's difficult to run your software.

Answer (score 0):

The gigenet cloud has some good cloud server hosting that's pretty cheap if you use the smaller instances. http://www.gigenet.com/cloud-servers.html

If you want something even more cost effective and are willing to compromise with the quality of the service, http://www.clubuptime.com/ is a decent VPS provider that I use for hosting non-critical applications.